# Viber bot: problem with opening images on iPhone

Tags: iphone, viber, viber-bot, viber-api

The image is successfully opened on Viber Android, Viber Macbook, Viber Windows, but the image does not open on an iPhone of any model.
[image]

Link: https://loyalty.aptekanizkihcen.ua/binary/img/01EBCE62A36084CE3DF9E5AB2FD796E03567973D.jpg

Comment: Any update here? I have the same issue on a viber bot. Iphones can't load the images

Answer (score 2):

Problem was missing parameter content-length in header.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit. Ty!

Comment: I also have this issue. Tried the Content-Length: header but nothing. Anyone found a solution for this?